# How to call Actions from Javascript Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, action, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have a requirement to call a Action Process from Javascript.
My Action Accept 2 Input Parameters and 1 output Param. Below is the screenshot of my Action

[image]
I have a textField in my Form, and on it's `onChange` event I'm calling this CallAction Method. Below is the JavaScript

```
function CallAction() {

        var actionName = "taqi_getPrice";
        var actionParameters = {
            "base": "USD",
            "TotalPrice": "200"
        };
        var actionResponse = activateCustomAction(actionName, actionParameters);
    }
    function activateCustomAction(actionName, actionParams) {

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/taqi_getPrice", false);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");

        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    alert('Success');
                } else {
                    alert('fail');
                    //Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        };
        req.send(JSON.stringify(actionParams));
    }
```

When running this script I'm getting the following error in chrome console

> POST https://techgulf.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/taqi_getPrice 404

Sometime it also says

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Modern good example: https://carldesouza.com/custom-actions-in-javascript-with-output-parameters-in-d365-and-powerapps/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I created Exact same Action as you mentioned in your screenshot, Except Entity I used is Account. I used below code to fire Action and it did worked for me without any issue and returned the value as expected.

[image]

May be for Testing you could provide static Guid and see how you get the result.

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.base = "123";
parameters.TotalPrice = "222";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts(DC86C293-CA4F-E911-A82F-000D3A385A1C)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.crmp_TestAction2", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the below line

```
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/taqi_getPrice", false);
```

like this one below:

```
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/taqi_cars(" + Id + ")/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.taqi_getPrice", false);
```

> Basically we need to pass name of the Entity Set with id of the record
>   followed by name of the action appended with Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.
>   In case of global action, we just need the
>   **`Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.<<ActionName>>`**.

[Reference](https://nishantrana.me/2017/05/27/sample-code-to-call-action-using-web-api-in-crm/)

Looks like you need a synchronous Action call execution (as you’re using **false** in `req.open`) otherwise you can use `Xrm.WebApi.online.execute` which is always Asynchronous. [Read more](https://debajmecrm.com/2018/07/20/calling-bound-actions-entity-actions-using-xrm-webapi-execute-in-dynamics-v9/)

Comment: Thank you for your Reply. I changed the code as you suggested but I'm still getting 404.

VM946:36 POST https://techgulf.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/taqi_cars(B4102B33-055A-E911-A81A-000D3ABA3DB5)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.taqi_getPrice 404

Comment: @MuhammadTaqi make sure your entity name taqi_cars is correct. Recommend to use CRM REST Builder for composing queries, to avoid errors.

Comment: are you sure that the prefix: "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM." should be present?

Comment: @Malachy may not be necessary am not sure, but CRM Rest Builder added it :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. Yes it was my mistake I was using wrong entity name. Everything is working fine now

Comment: @MuhammadTaqi glad you were able to sort this out. :)